# cURL Elasticsearch price comparison search aggs

Tags: php, elasticsearch, curl

Trying to achieve a jQuery/AJAX instant search towards an Elasticsearch index with PHP cURL, which should group items by a shared field value and grab the lowest available of another field value. The items in the index have ID, name, price. Several items will have the same ID, slightly different names, different price. The search is towards the name field, and should group items with the same ID, and grab the lowest price (this is for a price comparison demo project). How can this be achieved? I have the following in place now,

```
... get search input $searchQuery with $_GET[] ...

$query = '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "name" : "'.$searchQuery.'" }
    }
}';

... cURL request curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query) ...
```

The search is working but is showing all items where the name matches the search input, which is why I need to

- Group by ID value (aggregation?)
- Get any available or first available name
- Get lowest price of the grouped items

...To only show one item in search results, where one items name+lowest available price is displayed.

Can this is all be accomplished with ES or is PHP needed to group/grab the necessary values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$qyery = 
    '{
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "name": {
            "value": "'.$searchQuery.'"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ID",
            "size": 10000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "min_price_in_group": {
              "min": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "size": 0
    }';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is giving me the full db results (85k) whatever I search for. Any idea why? Edit: Nevermind saw a typo now. Got a "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default" so need to change the fieldtype I think

Comment: Unfortunately IDs can have both numbers and characters like 5578-AB1. Do you know if your query should work with "field": "ID.raw"?

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your fields in Elasticsearch?